# Recursively find and return a pattern in a list using only basic lisp

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, pattern-matching, lisp

The function I need to write takes two arguments: a pattern (p) and a list (L). I want to find the part of the list that contains the pattern as well as everything after the pattern. If the pattern is not in the list then return nil.

Example:

input: (find_pattern '(h e l p) '(i n e e d h e l p p l e a s e))

output: '(h e l p p l e a s e)

I can only use basic lisp functions (cond, car, cdr, cons, null, eq, /=). It needs to be recursive and cannot use things such as setq.

My strategy:

I reasoned the cases to be:

p = nil, L = nil: this occurs if the pattern is at the end of the list, therefore, return nil

p = nil, L = (none-nil value) : this occurs if pattern is in the middle of the list therefore return L

p = (non-nil value), L = nil : pattern was not found therfore return nil

p = (non-nil value), L= (non-nil value): if the car of both p and L are the same, recursively call on the cdr of p and L. If they are not the same, recursively call with p and the cdr of L.

My attempt:

```
(defun find_pattern (p L)
    (cond((null p) 
                  (cond ((null L) nil) ; p = nil, L = nil
                        (T L)))        ; p = nil, L != nil
         ((T 
                  (cond ((null L) nil) ; p != nil, L = nil
                        ((eq (car p), (car L)) ; p!= nil, L != nil
                         (cons ((car L) (find_pattern (cdr p) (cdr L))))))

)
```

Without running this I already see some problems:

If I find a partial-pattern match, I never return to the full pattern. So inputs such as '(a b c) '(d a b d a b c) would get the incorrect result. Also the partial results are being appended into the list.

Can someone set me on the right direction? How do I go about returning to searching for the full pattern when I come across partial patterns?

Comment: This attempt appears to have some syntactical errors as well, the comma in the expression `(eq (car p), (car L)`, the extra parenthesis in the else clause of the first `cond`, the extra parenthesis in the last expression `(cons ((car L)...` What Lisp implementation are you using that this is working at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in Common Lisp – the technique I'm using here is passing along a copy of `src` in the helper that keeps track of the current search position

```
(defun find-pattern-helper (xs ys src)
  (cond ((null xs)
         src)
        ((null ys)
         nil)
        ((eq (car xs) (car ys))
         (find-pattern-helper (cdr xs) (cdr ys) src))
        (T
         (find-pattern-helper pat (cdr src) (cdr src)))))

(defun find-pattern (pat src)
  (find-pattern-helper pat src src))
```

Or here it is in Racket... I kinda suck at Lisp so this was the only thing I could actually test it in

```
#lang racket

(define (find-pattern pat src)
  (let loop ((xs pat) (ys src) (src src))
    (cond ((null? xs)
           src)
          ((null? ys)
           '())
          ((eq? (car xs) (car ys))
           (loop (cdr xs) (cdr ys) src))
          (#t
           (loop pat (cdr src) (cdr src))))))

(find-pattern '(h e l p) '(i n e e d h e l p p l e a s e))
;; => '(h e l p p l e a s e)

(find-pattern '() '(h a y s t a c k))
;; => '(h a y s t a c k)

(find-pattern '(h a y s t a c k) '(h a y))
;; => '()
```